# Place the PlaceHolders

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to place some PlaceHolders for my dice in my app and I have the next problem.

[image: PlaceHolders]

I cannot put the one die next to other. What I am doing wrong?

Here is the Layout code of this "TableRow":

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.65" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="170dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

        </TableRow>
```

Should I remove the TableRow and use another Layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could use a horizontal LinearLayout. This will layout all the image views for you in the order they are added.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="170dp"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a relative layout and let each imageview use android:layout_toRightOf=""

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView7"
            android:src="@drawable/dice_ph_small" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to add a few tags to all your imageview depending on the dimension of the image square /rectangle adjust the scaletype property:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="cropCentre"<!--you might need to change the value of this field-->
```

if adjustviewbounds is set to true then the ImageView will adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.